# HTML row style, nth child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I need to apply this css:

```
tr tr:nth-child(even) { 
    background-color: #E6E6E6"; 
}
```

to this tag:

```
<tr style=.......
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

The reasons your css isn't working are:

1. Your css is trying to find a `tr` tag inside of another `tr` tag, so, instead of writing `tr tr:nth-child`, you should write `tr:nth-child`.
2. There is a double quote after the hex code `#E6E6E6"`.

Unfortunately it's impossible to put a `:nth-child` selector in a style attribute, try this instead:

```css
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #E6E6E6;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Nam at nunc gravida, commodo eros vel, ultrices metus.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Etiam eleifend porttitor pulvinar.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cras cursus ut erat convallis porttitor.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You can actually have a tr in another tr, in the case of a nested table; but I don't think the OP meant that. Anyway, the biggest problem with the OP's request is that it's impossible to put the `nth-child` functionality in a style attribute; you should mention that as well.

Comment: Thanks @MrLister I've updated my answer to mention that :)

Answer (score 0):

Think I don't understand your question well, but if I interpretate it correctly I could make it like so:

```css
tr:nth-child(2) { 
  background-color: blue;
}
tr:nth-child(4) { 
  background-color: black;
}
tr:nth-child(6) { 
  background-color: brown;
}
tr:nth-child(8) { 
  background-color: green;
}
tr:nth-child(10) { 
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>Text..</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Text..
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Text..
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Text..
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Text..
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Text..
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Text..
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Text..
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Text..
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Text..
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Also make sure your HTML and CSS is validated by W3C, there are some problems with yours, also a TR > TR:nth... ?? Why because a tablerow in a tablerow isn't a W3C validated guideline. Check your code here: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

The class table on your table is not necessary because using table is a default tag at your CSS.

Comment: And guys I forgot, my table has class = "table" which is default css style and I need in this table even rows in different color..

Comment: @Bopinko check the snippet, changed it by youre last comment.

Answer (score 0):

**This does not work**

tr tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: #E6E6E6"; }

And your background color has a double quote hex value does not need a quote.

**You can try this**

```css
table tr:nth-child(even){
  background-color: #E6E6E6;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>VIOLA</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>VIOLA</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>VIOLA</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>VIOLA</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>VIOLA</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>VIOLA</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>VIOLA</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```